# New Project With Empty Activity Results in Warnings

Tags: android

I am currently working on an app which is supposed to be backward compatible down to API Level 23 (Marshmallow). Unfortunately, even with the auto-generated empty activity and without any further changes in the project, Logcat mentions numerous warnings. Don't get me wrong: The app works just fine but nevertheless I would like to address these warnings as soon as possible.

Researching these warnings individually didn't lead to any avail, as available answers usually referred to problems within the source code. As I haven't made any changes to the auto-generated source code, these answers didn't help.

**Other attempts:**

- Restarting app
- Restarting emulator
- Clearing data
- Clearing cache
- Changing emulator (Same issue with Nexus 10, Nexus 5X and custom emulator)
- Creating project in latest Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4
- Running app on a connected device

In all situations Logcat mentions the following warnings:

**Marshmallow (API Level 23)**

```
09-03 16:27:08.793 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.847 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.856 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.864 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.874 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.883 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.893 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.902 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.911 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.921 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.930 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-03 16:27:08.933 4439-4439/com.example.test W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.test-1/lib/x86
09-03 16:27:08.999 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-03 16:27:09.201 4439-4494/com.example.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-03 16:27:09.273 4439-4439/com.example.test W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

**Nougat (API Level 25)**

```
09-03 16:25:35.515 3268-3268/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-03 16:25:35.598 3268-3268/com.example.test W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.test-1/lib/x86
09-03 16:25:35.793 3268-3268/com.example.test W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-03 16:25:36.069 3268-3333/com.example.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-03 16:25:36.138 3268-3268/com.example.test W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

**Oreo (API Level 26)**

```
09-03 16:23:18.671 6056-6056/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-03 16:23:19.045 6056-6089/com.example.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-03 16:23:21.491 6056-6056/com.example.test W/zygote: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
```

**Questions**

1. Is this a known phenomenon or am I right to address these warnings right away?
2. As I have reviewed the settings of the IDE, the building process and the emulator itself, I am running out of ideas. How would you proceed addressing these warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a known phenomenon or am I right to address these warnings right away?

All of that should be ignored.

> How would you proceed addressing these warnings?

By ignoring them.

None of them are coming from your Java code. The Android framework and underlying subsystems tend to be unnecessarily chatty in their log messages.